# nodejs-sqlite3 can't return from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, callback

I'm trying to return the result of a `SELECT` query, but due to the way the `nodejs-sqlite3` api is constructed, I need to get to the data via a callback. No problem I thought and did as follows.

```
var selectAllQuery =
        'SELECT * FROM challenge',
    selectQuery =
        'SELECT * FROM challenge WHERE signature = $signature';

exports.read = function (sig) {
    var result = [],
        callback = function(err, rows) {
            result = rows; // rows contains 3 items
        };

    db.serialize(function () {
        if (sig) db.all(selectQuery, {$signature: sig}, callback);
        else db.all(selectAllQuery, callback);
    });
    console.log(result); // prints []
    return result; // array is empty
};
```

As you can probably see from the comments, my code returns an empty array, despite the fact that `rows` contains data when the callback is called.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `read()` function returns before the DB callback is invoked. Your `read()` function needs to also accept a callback parameter and invoke it when either an error occurs or the data is available. This is a common Node idiom.

**UPDATE 1** -- You need to do something like this:

```
exports.read = function (sig, callback) {
    var result = [];

    db.serialize(function () {
        if (sig) db.all(selectQuery, {$signature: sig}, callback);
        else db.all(selectAllQuery, callback);
    });
};
```

Comment: is there no other way around? I don't want to clutter my system with unnecessary callbacks

Comment: since you can't return from a callback, none of them are unnecessary. if you need top-down-procedural code, use php.

Comment: I just tried with a callback, it still doesn't work. it results in the exact same issue one level higher up in the function chain. It has to terminate somewhere

Comment: Edit your question and post your updated code. I'm willing to bet you invoked the callback incorrectly.

Comment: I invoked it the exact same way

Comment: isn't there any way of getting the data OUT of the callback synchronously? That's all I need

Comment: I did add a callback argument to the function already, it just moves the issue one level up the function chain